# Display list of records on a Combo Box in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

How do i load records to a Grails combo-box (look screenshot below).

[image]

```
def bookList = Book.getAll();
```

Now how do i display the above book list in a Combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial to do once you have the `bookList` in your model for your GSP.

Assuming a controller action something like this:

```
class MyController {
  def index() {
     def bookList = Book.getAll()
     render(view: 'index', model: [bookList: bookList])
  }
}
```

And a domain like this:

```
class Book {
  String title
}
```

You can render it using the [g:select](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) tag in your GSP like this:

```
<g:select from="${bookList}" optionKey="id" optionValue="title" />
```